# perl: Regex, how to get data to the left of the found regex

Tags: regex, perl

I've been working with regex for certain patterns. I understand things like:

`$_ =~ /^\w{12,12}z$/` # Find a word thats 12 long and ends in z.

`$_ =~ /^[^aeiou]{8,8}$/i)` # Find a word that's 8 long, and does not have vowels, not case sensitive.

But I'm on a snag right now with something different. Let's take something simple:

```
$_ =~ s/angstroms?/nm/gi;
```

It will read the line and convert 'angstrom(s) to nm. A measurement. That part is correct but I'm having issues understanding how to grab the number before it. I.E. 22 angstroms. I want it to take the 22 and put it into a variable (`$1`).

I'm not looking for a 100% answer, more someone to explain it to me so I actually grasp the concept. The idea is that I am going to use that variable and convert it into a nm (0.1*angstrom value).

Comment: It's unnecessary to specify `$_ =~ ` when matching regexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```
$a = "512 angstrom";
$a =~ s/(\d+)\s*angstroms?/\1 nm/gi;
print "matched digits:\t", $1, "\n";
print "value of \$a:\t", $a, "\n";
```

The second line matches a list of digits plus additional whitespace and replaces it with the right side (note the backreference `\1`). Since the list of digits is captured in a group, this variable will be visible after the match as `$1`. The output, thus, is:

```
matched digits: 512
value of $a:    512 nm
```

Voila! The digits are captured in the variable `$1`. Additionally, you can perform the calculation within the substitution pattern:

```
$a =~ s{(\d+)\s*angstroms?}{@{[$1 * 0.1 ]} nm}gis;
```

or, easier readable as suggested in the comment,

```
$a =~ s/(\d+)\s*angstroms?/$1 * 0.1 ." nm"/gie;
```

will give the output

```
value of $a:    51.2 nm
```

which is possibly what you really want.

Comment: Thanks, I'm working on changing it now too. ($_ =~ s/(\d+)\s*angstroms?/$1*0.10 . " nm"/gie;) to modify the value. ;) Thank you for the explaination as well.

Comment: Got it, $_ =~ s/(\d*\.?\d+)\s*angstroms?/$1*0.10 . " nm"/gie; perfect, thanks too!

Comment: ... or you can use `e`, too ;-) Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
s#^(\d+) angstroms?$#${1}/10 . " nm"#e;
```

A substitution with the modifier `e` will *evaluate* the replacing part.
Here it takes the value in angstorm in the group 1, then uses this value (${1}) and divides it by 10 to obtain nanometer. The unit angstrom is then replaced by nm.

If you want to deal with decimal number, use:

```
s#^(\d+(?:\.\d*)?) angstroms?$#${1}/10 . " nm"#e;
```

You could also deal with the abreviation of Angstrom `Å`

```
 s#^(\d+(?:\.\d*)?) (?:angstroms?|Å$)#${1}/10 . " nm"#e;
```

In action:

```
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    s#^(\d+(?:\.\d*)?) (?:angstroms?|Å$)#${1}/10 . " nm"#e;
    say;
}


__DATA__
100 angstroms
10 Å
1 angstrom
12.3 Å
0.25 angstrom
```

**Output:**

```
10 nm
1 nm
0.1 nm
1.23 nm
0.025 nm
```

Comment: I was working on something similar

$_ =~ s/(\d+)\s*angstroms?/$1*0.10 . " nm"/gie;

Actually, except mine doesn't work when the values are lets say, 100.50 angstroms. But yeah I will take a look at yours too now.

Comment: Seem to have gotten it now.. $_ =~ s/(\d*\.?\d+)\s*angstroms?/$1*0.10 . " nm"/gie; ;)

Comment: @user3249223: See my edit to deal with decimal numbers.